# Query to find account-sharing violations (superman radar)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to implement a tracking system for a commercial product, to help with detecting account-sharing violations. To that end, the system has the following `tracking` table:

- `created` - date/time when an HTTP request was made
- `user_id` - id of the user that made the request
- `lat` - latitude of the IP address from which the request came
- `lng` - longitude of the IP address from which the request came

I'm completely stuck trying to implement a PostgreSQL (+Postgis) query that would give me a list of entries in the last `N` hours, grouped by `user_id`, for which there is at least one violation record - request that was made within `M` minutes from the original, while at a distance farther than can be crossed with direct line, moving at the speed of `S` km/h.

It should reveal all users that managed to make requests from such distance from each other that they could not cross at such speed and time interval, unless they are a superman.

For example, a typical set of parameters would be: Locate and group all users who in the last 24 hours managed to use the system from two or more locations within 10-minute interval, while at such distance it could not be crossed by moving in direct line at 120km/h.

Comment: How many users are there? How many requests per day per user? What's the peak request rate per minute? What are the expected ranges of values for `N`, `M` and `S`?

Comment: @Bohemian As many users as `user_id` refers to. As many requests as provided by the `tracking` table. Peak request rate is irrelevant. Ranges are within reason, and the typical example is provided.

Comment: The size of the number of users and the frequency of rows per user impacts the design of the query. For example, some simpler approaches will work well for smaller frequencies. Can you not provide a rough estimate (nearest power of 10) of the quantity of users and the typical rows per day per user (again, nearest power of 10 will do)?

Comment: **1)** Are you free to modify, expand these structures, add new ones? **2)** Is your data astract and planar (i.e. in-game x+y coords)? **3)** If those are real-world coordinates, what unit do they come in (degrees, meters, miles, nautical miles) **4)** Are they focused around one particular area, a city, a country, a continent? It doesn't matter which one as much as just how concentrated/localised/focused they are. **5)** Do you plan this to be a periodic job, a report, or do you consider real-time alerts or monitoring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add a proper `geometry(Point,3857)` column so that you don't have to litter your query with geometry construction.

```sql
alter table tracking 
  add column point geometry (Point,3857) 
  generated always as (st_setsrid(st_makepoint(lat,lng),3857)) stored;
```

With that, you can use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) to get the earlier/later location, [`st_distance()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) between them and [time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE) it took to move, [`st_makeline()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) to also see the path. [Demo with examples:](https://dbfiddle.uk/R4VHknIh)

```sql
with 
 distance_and_time as (
    select created, user_id, st_astext(point),
      st_distance(       point,  lag(point)  over w1)/1000 as move_dist_km,
      st_makeline(       point,  lag(point)  over w1)      as move_path,
      extract(epoch from created-lag(created)over w1)/3600 as move_time_h
    from tracking 
    where created >= now() - '1 hour'::interval * 24 --last N hours
    window w1 as (partition by user_id order by created)
    order by user_id,created  )
,speeds as (
    select *, move_dist_km/move_time_h as move_speed_kmph 
    from distance_and_time  )
,violations as (
    select user_id, created from speeds
    where   move_time_h * '1 hour'::interval 
            <= '1 minute'::interval * 10     --M minutes from the original
    and   move_speed_kmph > 120  )           --moving at the speed of S km/h
select *, (s.user_id,s.created)=(v.user_id,v.created) as is_violation 
from speeds s inner join violations v using (user_id);
```

1. [`st_distancespheroid()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html) will typically provide higher precision, which you don't necessarily need.
2. Make sure what units and order `lat` and `lng` are in and that you're aware of how [SRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system) work.
3. It might be useful to later use [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/) to inspect in the suspicious users' paths, plotting them with `st_makeline(point order by created)`, or by building line segments out of their consecutive locations, like above.
4. Depending on what system this is and how you react to violations, I'd expect someone to probe you by spoofing different speeds in different time periods to try and figure out your parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As a single query you may try this:

```sql
SELECT t1.user_id,
       t1.created AS t1_created,
       t1.lat AS t1_lat,
       t1.lng AS t1_lng,
       LEAD(created, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created) AS t2_created
FROM tracking t1
WHERE created >= NOW() - INTERVAL '24 hours'
GROUP BY user_id, t1_created, t1_lat, t1_lng
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND MAX(EXTRACT(epoch FROM (LEAD(created, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created) - created))) / 60.0 <= 10 AND ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_MakePoint(t1.lng, t1.lat), ST_MakePoint(t2.lng, t2.lat)) > 120 * MAX(EXTRACT(epoch FROM (LEAD(created, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created) - created))) / 3600.0;
```

The query filters last 24 hours to reduce the total row count (so you deal with roughly same amount of data everyday). Then it locates and groups all users who managed to use the system from two or more locations, filtering the group by rows that are within a 10-minute interval while at such distance it could not be crossed by moving in a direct line at 120km/h.

Comment: What are `lat2` and `lng2` parameters?

Comment: You are right, sorry. Modified from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

Use lead() to find the next logging entry by user and date. Join the next logging entry and use ST_LengthSperoid() and age() to calculate time and distance deltas. Use this deltas to calculate the speed and filter the data.

### long story

Let's create some demo data:

```sql
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tracking;

CREATE TABLE tracking(
    created timestamp,
    user_id integer,
    lat numeric,
    lng numeric
);

--TRUNCATE TABLE tracking;

INSERT INTO tracking VALUES
-- user 1
('2023-05-02 8:00', 1, 50.01, 8.02),
('2023-05-02 8:30', 1, 50.02, 8.03),
('2023-05-02 8:55', 1, 50.03, 8.01),
-- user 1 violation
('2023-05-02 8:05', 1, 53.00, 7.00),
-- user 2
('2023-05-02 9:00', 2, 40.01, 8.03),
('2023-05-02 9:30', 2, 40.02, 8.02),
('2023-05-02 9:55', 2, 40.03, 8.03);
```

I guess, [lead()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) will do the trick, as it returns the timestamp of the following entry ordered by timestamp:

```sql
SELECT 
    user_id,
    created as t1_created,
    lat as t1_lat,
    lng as t1_lng,
    
    LEAD(created,1) OVER(
        PARTITION BY user_id
        ORDER BY created
    ) as t2_created 
FROM 
    tracking
-- also possible to check for M and N at this stage
;
```

which leads to (no pun intended )

[image]

afterwards, you could join the data:

```sql
WITH next_timestamp as (
SELECT 
    user_id,
    created as t1_created,
    lat as t1_lat,
    lng as t1_lng,
    
    LEAD(created,1) OVER(
        PARTITION BY user_id
        ORDER BY created
    ) as t2_created
FROM 
    tracking
-- also possible to check for M and N at this stage
)

SELECT 
    next_timestamp.*,
    t2.lng as t2_lng,
    t2.lat as t2_lat
FROM
    next_timestamp
JOIN
    tracking t2
ON 
    next_timestamp.t2_created = t2.created AND
    next_timestamp.user_id = t2.user_id
```

which returns

[image]

and do some math

```sql
WITH next_timestamp as (
SELECT 
    user_id,
    created as t1_created,
    lat as t1_lat,
    lng as t1_lng,
    
    LEAD(created,1) OVER(
        PARTITION BY user_id
        ORDER BY created
    ) as t2_created
    
FROM 
    tracking
),

next_location AS (
    SELECT 
        next_timestamp.*,
        t2.lng as t2_lng,
        t2.lat as t2_lat
    FROM
        next_timestamp
    JOIN
        tracking t2
    ON 
        next_timestamp.t2_created = t2.created AND
        next_timestamp.user_id = t2.user_id
),

with_deltas AS (

    SELECT
        *,
        age(t2_created, t1_created) as delta_time,
        ST_LengthSpheroid(
            ST_MakeLine(
                ST_Point(t1_lng, t1_lat),
                ST_Point(t2_lng, t2_lat)
            ),
            'SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]'
            )/1000 as delta_distance_km

    FROM
        next_location   
)

SELECT 
    *,
    EXTRACT(epoch FROM delta_time)/3600 as delta_time_hours,
    delta_distance_km / (EXTRACT(epoch FROM delta_time)/3600) as speed_kmh
FROM 
    with_deltas
```

which returns the desired structure:

[image]

at this time, you could add a filter like

```sql
-- include CTEs from above

SELECT 
    *,
    EXTRACT(epoch FROM delta_time)/3600 as delta_time_hours,
    delta_distance_km / (EXTRACT(epoch FROM delta_time)/3600) as speed_kmh
FROM 
    with_deltas
WHERE
     age(now(), t1_created) < '24 hour'::interval AND -- test for M
     age(t2_created, t1_created) < '10 Minute'::interval AND --test for N
     delta_distance_km / (EXTRACT(epoch FROM delta_time)/3600) > 120 --test for S
```

to get the desired user_ids:

```sql
-- include CTEs from above

SELECT 
    DISTINCT(user_id)
FROM 
    with_deltas
WHERE
     age(now(), t1_created) < '24 hour'::interval AND -- test for M
     age(t2_created, t1_created) < '10 Minute'::interval AND --test for N
     delta_distance_km / (EXTRACT(epoch FROM delta_time)/3600) > 120 --test for S
```

Comment: Do I understand right that this ignores parameter `M` in the question, to specify the maximum time spread? It is that parameter, in combination with the speed (which you do account for) that determine the logic/strategy for detecting violations.

Comment: Actually M and N aren't tested, as it can be done at multiple places. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @vitaly-t i updated the answer. I think, i would filter in `next_timestamp`, when there are a lot of entrys in `tracking` or if this is used in a view. Filtering by `S`, `M` and `N` as last step looks cleaner, as all limitations are testest at one place. I don't know, how this will perform on a large dataset.

Comment: This is a very good help, thank you, but I've just put a maximum bounty on it, to see if it can attract more answers ;)

Comment: Why use a `JOIN` instead of simply doing `lead()` again?

Answer (score -1):

The approach: For a user_id

- get the previous `created`, `lat`, `lng`
- calculate the distance and time between entries
- the distance and time will give you the speed

The implementation:

- Create CTE order_logins using `row_number()` to order the logins from the tracking table. The `H` filter can go here to limit the entries from the orginal table.
- Create CTE distnace_logins by self joining order_logins on `user_id` and `login_order` to get a the current and previous `created`, `lat`, `lng`
- Calculate the distance with the haversine formula and the time in seconds with `extract`
- In the final query, calculate speed: `kmph_to_location`

.

```
with 
ordered_logins as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by created) login_order 
    from QUESTIONS.TRACKING
    --where created >  put your H filter
),
distance_logins as (
    select
        ol.user_id,
        ol.created,
        2 * 6371 * ASIN( SQRT( POWER(SIN(RADIANS((prev.lat - ol.lat) / 2)), 2) + COS(RADIANS(ol.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(prev.lat)) * POWER(SIN(RADIANS((prev.lng - ol.lng) / 2)), 2) ) ) km,
        extract(epoch from prev.created - ol.created ) seconds
    from
        ordered_logins ol
        join ordered_logins prev on
            ol.user_id = prev.user_id
            and ol.login_order = prev.login_order - 1
)
select
    user_id,
    created,
    km,
    seconds,
    km / ( seconds / 3600.0 ) kmph_to_location
from
    distance_logins    
/*
put your filters
where    
    km / ( seconds / 3600.0 ) > S
    seconds / 60 > M
*/
```

here's the setup with some sample data:

```
create schema if not exists QUESTIONS
;
create table if not exists QUESTIONS.TRACKING(
    created timestamp,
    user_id int,
    lat double,
    lng double
)
;
insert into QUESTIONS.TRACKING VALUES
    ( current_timestamp,                     1, 40.604252, -74.44612 ),
    ( current_timestamp - interval '1' hour, 1, 40.79185, -74.245241 ),
    ( current_timestamp - interval '3' hour, 1, 40.153024, -74.03372 ),
    ( current_timestamp - interval '7' hour, 1, 40.971956, -73.96166 ),
    ( current_timestamp - interval '5' hour, 1, 39.625291, -74.77705 ),
    ( current_timestamp,                     2, 40.828922, -74.11064 ),
    ( current_timestamp - interval '1' hour, 2, 39.59899, -74.36573 ),
    ( current_timestamp - interval '3' hour, 2, 40.153024, -74.299692 )
;
```

and the results:

| USER_ID | CREATED | KM | SECONDS | KMPH_TO_LOCATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-02 17:06:59.728602 | 26.868598995476276 | 3600 | 26.868598995476276 |
| 1 | 2023-06-02 15:06:59.728602 | 73.2528295918482 | 7200 | 36.6264147959241 |
| 1 | 2023-06-02 11:06:59.728602 | 164.93579038044533 | 7200 | 82.467895190222665 |
| 1 | 2023-06-02 13:06:59.728602 | 86.40274604424121 | 7200 | 43.201373022120605 |
| 2 | 2023-06-02 17:06:59.728602 | 138.4666555733752 | 3600 | 138.4666555733752 |
| 2 | 2023-06-02 15:06:59.728602 | 61.86297059586338 | 7200 | 30.93148529793169 |

Comment: fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/bkSDB75f